# Find out which coordinate changes at faster rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, differentiation

Suppose we have a particle, which moves along a path (in x-y plane) and say its path is the curve, $ 12y = x^3 $ .

I need to find out which coordinate (x or y) changes at faster rate at any given point, say at $ x = 10 $ ?

Only this much data is known.

Comment: Are x and y functions of time?  Do you want a derivative with respect to time or some other variable?  Please clarify.

Comment: But how does your particle move along the path as a function of time? Does it speed up or slow down? Does it stop and turn around?

Comment: @probably_someone See now, I fully mentioned what I had.

Comment: This path is independent of any function, such as time

Comment: Then your question does not have a well-defined answer.

Comment: Any help is accepted.

Comment: Hint: You have an equality that says something about the relation between $y$ and $x$. Differentiating with respect to time yields another equality, this time saying something about the relation between $\dot y$ and $dot x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to unknown functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and we want to know which of the two grows at a faster rate. Well,

$$ \frac{ \frac{dy}{dt} }{ \frac{dx}{dt} } = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

so if the slope of the path is greater than 1 in absolute value, then $y$ is growing faster, otherwise $x$ is.

Comment: can you please show me the steps, I am a beginner.

Comment: The steps to what? Do you know how to take a derivative?

Comment: That was a fairly creative answer.  Thanks, @Javier.

Comment: Yes, i know ho to take derivative but i m still confused. So please show me all steps

Comment: The steps are right there in my answer. From $y(x)$ calculate $dy/dx$, and at your given point find out if it's greater or lesser than 1.